# iPhone App Dev - mysql-> php -> iphone

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, xcode

I have the following table in my database:

```
Questions
int:questionId(PK)
varchar:questionTitle
int:questionNumber
int:sectionId(FK)
```

I have built pretty much the same structured class in objective c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Question : NSObject {
    NSInteger qId;
    NSString* qTitle;
    NSInteger qNumber;  
}

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger qId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* qTitle;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger qNumber;

@end


#import "Question.h"


@implementation Question
@synthesize qId, qTitle, qNumber;

@end
```

My question is, is there anyway to map the structures? do compatibility frameworks exist for iphone php communication?

e.g. get php to echo an object array and assign elements to question objects

Comment: I don't know if it is what you are looking for, but I throw my PHP values into an associative array,encode it as JSON, and use [SBJSON](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) to parse the JSON into an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to build a small "service" that encodes your items in json and returns them via http, here's the docs for that:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php

As Katfish above mentioned, you'll want ot use the SBJSON[1] library in your project in combination with the NSURLConnection/NSURLRequest or the ASIHTTP[2] library. ASIHTTP is probably easier if you aren't familiar with either method of http access in Cocoa/Obj-C.

Here's a good example:

http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

[1] http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

[2] http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/